# Compartir una imagen a whatsapp desde mi aplicación

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código y envío mensajes a mi whatsapp desde mi aplicación:

```
Intent y = new Intent();
y.setPackage ("com.whatsapp");
y.setAction (Intent_ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"mensaje enviado a whatsapp");
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(y)
```

listo, con esto se envía a Whatsapp un mensaje, que en este caso es: `mensaje enviado a whatsapp`.

Mi pregunta es si quiero enviar una imagen que está en mi memoria interna del móvil, ¿como hago?

Cambio `intent.setType("text/plain");`  por `intent.setType("image/png");`,
cambio `putExtra(intente.EXTRA_TEXT,"mensaje enviado a whatsapp") ;` por la imagen pero ¿cómo la escribo?, no entiendo cómo leer la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen (repito en mi caso la imagen se llama `hola.png` y se encuentra en la memoria interna del móvil dentro del directorio `DCMI`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes abrir por medio de intents las imágenes desde la galería:

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST= 1;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Podemos hacer uso de `shareIntent`, al cual le pasaremos la *Uri* de la imagen.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            String stringUri;
            stringUri = uri.toString();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            enviarAwhatsapp(stringUri); // Aquí le envío la uri como string a ese método
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void enviarAwhatsapp(String uriString){ //Recibimos el string y lo convertimos a Uri
     Uri ur;
     ur = Uri.parse(uriString);
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ur);// Le pasamos el uri
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

      try {
            startActivity(shareIntent);


      Toast.makeText(tuActivity.this, "Enviar a Whatsapp", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                 Toast.makeText(tuActivity.this, "Whatsapp no instalado", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como yo lo hago es 
:

```
    PackageManager packageManager =getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "CUALQUIER TEXTO";

        PackageInfo info=getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir con"));
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp no esta instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: Esto es para un texto el OP pregunta oara una image.